# How to add a block inside order sales view in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, adminhtml

#### Sales Order View in Admin panel

[image]

#### This is the layout.xml

```
<layout>
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_tab_info">
        <block type="booking/sales_order_view_reservationbooking" name="reservationbooking" template="booking/sales/order/view/reservationbooking.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

#### This is the block in my module

```
<?php

    class Actino_Booking_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Reservationbooking extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    }
```

#### Here is my explanation about what i want to achieve

In core adminhtml i edited the **sales/order/view/info.phtml**.. I know that **Never edit the core files**, but this is only for test for which i want to display my template around the orders view. and then if this works I should have to create or rewrite the info.phtml.

#### here is my custom reservationbooking.phtml

[image]

and in info.phtml i write a code to view this layout

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reservationbooking');?>
```

This is not working. I cant see the text "reservation booking data" in sales order view. without modifying any core files ? 
My question is how to add custom field in sales order view ?

Answer (score 0):

Once a try

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>yourmodule/sales/order/view/reservationbooking.phtml</template>
        </action> 
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Create a file in the following 
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/yourmodule/sales/order/view/reservationbooking.phtml`

Now you can add your stuff to the `reservationbooking.phtml` inside your module, without change the core files

Comment: The problem of that is What if other module also rewrite the order_info ? Yes i could do that but, what im trying to render a custom box before info.phtml applied in information tab.

Comment: lets say for example Items ordered box is already there, and i want also to write my own box data before info.phtml rendered. adding a block into a parent bock info, and rendered all the child.

Comment: look at [add custom block after items block into order view page](https://sohelrana09.wordpress.com/2014/03/05/how-to-add-custom-block-after-items-block-into-order-view-page-in-magento/)